# I sent a transaction and got a hash, but blockchain explorers don't see it. What happened?

Tags: transactions, synchronization, confirmations, explorers

I used in the eth client `web3.eth.sendTransaction({from:sender,to:receiver,value:amount)` to try send some ether, typed yes to the question, then got a hash number  `0x6ec7a8ea0e4cf1b381abea7a03e84338fe75a1c8f47767a8da18255508066ac5`.

Looking at [etherscan](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x6ec7a8ea0e4cf1b381abea7a03e84338fe75a1c8f47767a8da18255508066ac5) it looks like the transaction is non-existent.

Checking my accounts values, they didn't move.

How can I know it failed or succeeded and if it failed, then why?

Comment: i have same question。how to fit？

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/35696)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what could have gone wrong. Are you connected to the network? Are you fully synced (if you are not fully synced your sender account might have the wrong nonce)?

Comment: I think it's that, not fully synced : 12:53:34.508|eth  Block import 804227 548 ms
for whatever reason I gor a PeerCount dropping after a while whereas I lauched the client with  eth -j -i -x 50

Answer (score 1):

You need to query your client somehow to figure out the reason it didn't go through. In geth you can retrieve pending transactions and in general inspect the current pool of queued transactions to see if something's off. In addition geth replies with a big warning if it doesn't accept a transaction for some reason. Don't know how eth does it though.